# Lightning Navigation is not working after Summer 19 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I used lightning:navigation to navigate from one component to another component, everything worked fine until the summer 2019 release.

Should I change it to force:navigateToComponent ?.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your minimal required code?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please make sure to include the relevant portions of your code, along with the specific issue you are struggling with and the complete text and location of any errors. See [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more about our expectations, and please edit your question to add information rather than posting comments.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into this issue and found this solution:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigate_add_params.htm

> state parameters must be namespaced. For example, a managed package with the 
>   namespace abc with a parameter accountId is represented as abc__accountId. The 
>   namespace for custom components is c__.Parameters without a namespace are 
>   reserved for Salesforce use. This namespace restriction is introduced under a 
>   critical update in Winter ’19 and enforced in Summer ’19.

It looks like if you are developing inside a managed package you now need to prepend your namespace to your url parameters, or if you are navigating to a custom component you need to prepend c__ to the parameters.